# Overlapping classes under the same package in java

Tags: java

I am learning Java on my own, i came a cross this interesting example and i found it difficult to understand it.

What i want to know is, what is this called in Java when you have several classes under the same package all of them are Overlapping. Please take a look at the example below ? Note that none of the classes use implements, interface, abstract, extends etc...

And is it possible to find more of these examples ?

class Flightplan

```
public class Flightplan {
    String type;
    int seat;
    String from;
    String to;
         // Other local variables, style captain ...
    Person[] passenger;
    int counter = 0;

    Flightplan (String t, int s, String startPlace, String d) {
        type = t;
        seat = s;
        passenger = new Person [s-1]; // kapten tar ett säte 
          // Captain takes a seat
        from = startPlace;
        to = d;
    }

    void book (Person p, String f, String t) {
        if (f.equals(from) && t.equals(to)) {
            passenger[counter] = p;
            to = t;
            counter++;
        }
                else System.out.println(p.name + " try to book a wrong flight !");
    }

    void flyg() {
        System.out.println("On the plane " + this.typ + " reser"); 
        for (int i = 0; i < passenger.length && passenger[i] != null; i++) {
            System.out.println(passenger[i].name + ", ");
        }
        System.out.println("\n");
        from = to;
    }

}
```

class Person

```
public class Person {
    String name;
    String from;
    String to;
    String stopover;
    int bags;
    Flightplan flight;

    Person (String n, String f, String m, String t, int v) {
        name = n;
        from = f;
        stopover = m; // Only one stopover is approved, otherwise we would enter this as an array
        to = t;
        bags = v;
    }

    void boardNextLeg(Flightplan plan) {
        flight = plan;

// Function bar for a stopover due. if-kit building
        if (!stopover.equals(null) && flight.from.equals(this.from) && flight.to.equals(this.stopover)) { 
            System.out.print(this.name + " is now in between");
            System.out.println(from + " and " + stopover);
            flight.book(this, from, stopover);
        }
        else if (flight.from.equals(this.from) && flight.to.equals(this.to)) {
            System.out.println(from + " och " + to);
            flight.book(this, from, to);
        }

                else System.out.println(this.name + " could not be booked on a flight");
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is this called in Java when you have
>   several classes under the same package all of them are Overlapping ?

This is NOT overlapping, rather this is called **circular dependency** because your `Flightplan` and `Person` are dependent on each other, which is bad design and poorly developed.

Basically Circular Dependencies cause lots of issues (like `OutofMemoryError`) if not properly used, so they should be avoided in between the classes/packages.

You can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5490132/dealing-with-a-circular-dependency) for more details on circular dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

By overlapping you mean that they have member variables with the same names?  Each class has a different list of member variables, and one class presents no restrictions to another class.

I think this is called "Several classes that each deal with similar data values"